# Define SQL Plus Variable

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I create a variable in SQL Plus with commands:

```
Variable getstatus number
Begin
:getstatus:= select trim(status) from AML.amletl_load_status where mov_date 
in(select max(mov_date) mov_date from AML.amletl_load_status);
End;
/
```

It raised

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol “SELECT” when expecting one of these
> following: <-+ case mode not null a double-quoted delimited -
> identifiers continue avg count ...
>
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
> “END”.

Comment: it still show the same error

Answer (score 0):

You should `select`

```
into :variable_name
     ^
     | colon sign here
```

Example based on Scott's schema:

```
SQL> var getstatus number
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    select max(empno) into :getstatus from emp
  3      where deptno in (select min(deptno) from dept);
  4  end;
  5  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print getstatus

 GETSTATUS
----------
      7934

SQL>
```

Applied to your code:

```
Variable getstatus number

Begin
  select trim(status) into :getstatus from AML.amletl_load_status 
    where mov_date in (select max(mov_date) mov_date from AML.amletl_load_status);
End;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign the output of "select" into the variable as:

```
"variable:= select;"
```

But, you can use the "INTO" clause to assign this values into a variable as:

```
"select x into v_x"
```

As you are assigning the output of select into bind variable you have to use ":" prefix with INTO clause as below:

```
Variable getstatus number;

Begin
select trim(status)
  into :getstatus
from AML.amletl_load_status where mov_date 
in(select max(mov_date) mov_date from AML.amletl_load_status);
End;
/
```